# Get UI Kit Filter with multiple containers

Tags: getuikit

Is it possible to have two containers for the filter and only one controller?

Right now it's only filtering the first container, can't do much as my layout is a masonry grid in a loop so i need the headers and the separate containers...

[Here's](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pmgxEd?editors=1010) what I'm trying to do.

```
<div uk-filter="target: .js-filter">

    <ul class="uk-subnav uk-subnav-pill">
        <li uk-filter-control><a href="#">All</a></li>
        <li uk-filter-control="[data-tags*='city']"><a href="#">City</a></li>
        <li uk-filter-control="[data-tags*='coast']"><a href="#">Coast</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="js-filter uk-text-center" uk-grid>
        <div class="uk-width-1-1" data-tags="city coast"><h2>header</h2></div>

        <li class="uk-width-1-3" data-tags="city">
            <div class="uk-card uk-card-secondary uk-card-body">City</div>
        </li>
        <li class="uk-width-1-3" data-tags="coast">
            <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Coast</div>
        </li>
        <li class="uk-width-1-3" data-tags="city">
            <div class="uk-card uk-card-secondary uk-card-body">City</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="js-filter uk-text-center" uk-grid>
        <div class="uk-width-1-1" data-tags="city coast"><h2>header 2</h2></div>

        <li class="uk-width-1-3" data-tags="city">
            <div class="uk-card uk-card-secondary uk-card-body">City</div>
        </li>
        <li class="uk-width-1-3" data-tags="coast">
            <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Coast</div>
        </li>
        <li class="uk-width-1-3" data-tags="city">
            <div class="uk-card uk-card-secondary uk-card-body">City</div>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Same problem:((

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't figured it out yet, and if I am understanding correctly, all you need to do is use one ul tag instead of two.

```
<div uk-filter="target: .js-filter">

<ul class="uk-subnav uk-subnav-pill">
    <li uk-filter-control><a href="#">All</a></li>
    <li uk-filter-control="[data-tags*='city']"><a href="#">City</a></li>
    <li uk-filter-control="[data-tags*='coast']"><a href="#">Coast</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="js-filter uk-text-center" uk-grid>
    <div class="uk-width-1-1" data-tags="city coast"><h2>header</h2></div>

    <li class="uk-width-1-3" data-tags="city">
        <div class="uk-card uk-card-secondary uk-card-body">City</div>
    </li>
    <li class="uk-width-1-3" data-tags="coast">
        <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Coast</div>
    </li>
    <li class="uk-width-1-3" data-tags="city">
        <div class="uk-card uk-card-secondary uk-card-body">City</div>
    </li>
    <div class="uk-width-1-1" data-tags="city coast"><h2>header 2</h2></div>

    <li class="uk-width-1-3" data-tags="city">
        <div class="uk-card uk-card-secondary uk-card-body">City</div>
    </li>
    <li class="uk-width-1-3" data-tags="coast">
        <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Coast</div>
    </li>
    <li class="uk-width-1-3" data-tags="city">
        <div class="uk-card uk-card-secondary uk-card-body">City</div>
    </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.6.20/css/uikit.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.6.20/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<div class="uk-container">
<div uk-filter="target: .js-filter">

    <ul class="uk-subnav uk-subnav-pill">
        <li uk-filter-control><a href="#">All</a></li>
        <li uk-filter-control="[data-tags*='city']"><a href="#">City</a></li>
        <li uk-filter-control="[data-tags*='coast']"><a href="#">Coast</a></li>
    </ul>
<div class="uk-width-1-1 uk-text-center"><h2>Header 1</h2></div>
    <ul class="js-filter uk-text-center" uk-grid>
        <li class="uk-width-1-3" data-tags="city">
            <div class="uk-card uk-card-secondary uk-card-body">City</div>
        </li>
        <li class="uk-width-1-3" data-tags="coast">
            <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Coast</div>
        </li>
        <li class="uk-width-1-3" data-tags="city">
            <div class="uk-card uk-card-secondary uk-card-body">City</div>
        </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="uk-width-1-1 uk-text-center" ><h2>Header 2</h2></div>
  <ul class="js-filter uk-text-center" uk-grid>
        <li class="uk-width-1-3" data-tags="city">
            <div class="uk-card uk-card-secondary uk-card-body">City</div>
        </li>
        <li class="uk-width-1-3" data-tags="coast">
            <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Coast</div>
        </li>
        <li class="uk-width-1-3" data-tags="city">
            <div class="uk-card uk-card-secondary uk-card-body">City</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Headers should not be in filter container to avoid affect them.